# When I try to comment with Facebook comment box from mobile (specially Opera Mini), "page not found" error occures

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-comments

This is my first query on such a big platform so at first I am sorry for any of my shortcomings here. I have a problem with facebook comment box plugin in mobile. My visitors can not comment from their mobile browser (specially Opera Mini). When they try to post a comment, "Page not found" error appears after clicking the "comment" button. It only happens with my site's mobile version. But sometimes the comment box works there too.

I don't know why it occurs.

Would you please help me to solve this problem? I wish my visitors could comment from their any mobile browser using facebook comment box...

I am waiting for your kind reply.

Thanks everyone,
Arafat.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mobile="auto-detected" where 
href="    "  where the facebook comment code was placed.

Comment: "...where href="" where the facebook..." that seems kind of confusing. Can you make that a bit clearer?